# jquery form change validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I am working on a calculator like code. User will be submitting form multiple times and I need to store the result of calculations only if form changes. i.e., first time user clicks "calculate" button - send indication to servlet, calculate the result and save result in DB. If user clicks "calculate" button again without changing any fields in form - send indication to servlet that no form changes were made.

I tried to use .serializeArray() on a form but it doesn't work: every time I click on "calculate" button without changing any form fields it tells me that form has changed... I'd appreciate any input!

Oh, for some reason jsfiddle example doesn't trigger calculate click but works for me locally.
https://jsfiddle.net/oqqbhjve/4/

My HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
   <input id="field1" name="field1" maxlength="4" type="text" />
   <br />
   <select name="field2" >
      <option value="0" selected>- Select Brand</option>
      <option value="1">Description 1</option>
      <option value="2">Description 2</option>
   </select>
   <br /><br />
   <div id="results">   
     <input id="calculate" type="button" name="calculate" value="Calculate" />
     <input id="reset" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
   </div>
</form>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var form_changed = "No";
   var form_original_data = $("#myForm").serializeArray(); 

   $('#calculate').click(function() {

   var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();

   if ($("#myForm").serializeArray() != form_original_data) {
      form_changed = "Yes";
   }
   alert(form_changed);

   $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"myServlet",
      data:data,
      cache: false,
      success:function(html)
   {
      $("#results").hide();
      $("#results").html(html).fadeIn("slow");
   }
   });
});
});
```

Comment: Since serializeArray() returns an object, it's probably saying they changed because they are not the same object.  You'll have to compare some other way, maybe compare both of them converted to strings.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oqqbhjve/5/ you didn't have jquery included in your fiddle.  open your console to see errors like that.

Comment: Doh, I feel stupid... Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/oqqbhjve/17/

```
$(function() {
    var $form = $('#myForm'),
        form_original_data = $form.serializeArray(),
        original_data_string = JSON.stringify(form_original_data);

    $('#calculate').on('click', function() {
        var form_current_data = $form.serializeArray(),
            current_data_string = JSON.stringify(form_current_data),
            form_changed = (current_data_string !== original_data_string);

        console.log(form_changed);

        if (form_changed) {
            original_data_string = current_data_string;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myServlet",
                data: form_current_data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    //$("#results").hide();
                    //$("#results").html(html).fadeIn("slow");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The above only submits if the form changed.  So if it submits your backend can assume the form_changed was true.

It also updates the original_data_string so that after it submits it becomes the new base line.

Comment: I would have never thought of this. Thanks for your help! Btw, is there a way to send form_changed variable to servlet from my jquery?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to send an indication to my backend that no changes were made, so do not insert results into DB.

Comment: Btw, after implementing your original code above, it doesn't work for all consecutive 'calculate' clicks if no changes were made. Even though two strings are the same. See updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oqqbhjve/16/ it always says Yes

Comment: Correct, after Yes, the new values should become original and if no changes and click is made it should say No

Comment: Updated.  After it submits the data becomes the new original.

Comment: Perfect! You rock Taplar!

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to check the input field change event:

```js
$(function () {
  var form_changed = "No";
  var form_original_data = $("#myForm").serializeArray();

  $("form :input").change(function() {
    form_changed = "Yes";
  });
  $("#reset").click(function(e) {
    form_changed = "No";
  });

  $('#calculate').click(function() {
    var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
    $('#alert').text(form_changed);
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"myServlet",
      data:data,
      cache: false,
      success:function(html)
      {
        $("#results").hide();
        $("#results").html(html).fadeIn("slow");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" method="POST">
    <input id="field1" name="field1" maxlength="4" type="text" />
    <br />
    <select name="field2" >
        <option value="0" selected>- Select Brand</option>
        <option value="1">Description 1</option>
        <option value="2">Description 2</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="results">
        <input id="calculate" type="button" name="calculate" value="Calculate" />
        <input id="reset" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
</form>

<p id="alert"></p>
```

Comment: Are there any pros or cons in this solution compared to objects conversion to strings?